# java programming and sql dividing sum of two column

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
      try{
       String sum="",sum1="";
          String sql = "select sum(unit) from Result where idNumber=?";
          pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          pst.setString(1,issearchTextField.getText());
          rs=pst.executeQuery();
          if(rs.next()){
           sum = rs.getString("sum(unit)");

          }



          String sql1 = "select sum(ugp) from Result where idNumber=?";
          PreparedStatement pst1=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
          pst1.setString(1,issearchTextField.getText());
           ResultSet rs1=pst.executeQuery();
          if(rs1.next()){
           sum1 = rs1.getString("sum(ugp)");

          }

          String rst = (sum)/(sum1);
         ccnameTextField.setText(rst);
      }
      catch(Exception ex){

      }
       finally{
    try{
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    }
```

/* goodday everyone, please i'm trying to get the sum of two columns
       in the database,and divide these sums which will be an output to  textField,below is what i tried. please help me...*/

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in single query

```
select sum(unit)/NULLIF(sum(ugp),0)
from Result 
where idNumber=?
```

`NULLIF` is used to avoid *Divide by zero* error

Comment: i have tried it works,but the problem is, i am trying to make the result  in 2 decimal place.how can i do that?

Comment: @SaddamMusaMohammed - What is the data type of `unit` and `ugp` columns and what is the current result

Answer (score 0):

For 2 decimal format you can use like this:

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d)); //1.23
```

Comment: the datatypes are integer for unit and double for ugp